# overflow container with bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, overflow

My aim is to create a container that have `overflow x` and `overflow y` with `auto` because what ever I will render there (large tables) the client should see a "window" with scroll able content + it will be greate if that contaner works with bootstrap 4 `col` and `row`. I don't wanna hardcode height and width.

I thought that code should work, but it doesn't

```
.overflow-table {
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.overflow-table .row {
    display: block;
}

<div class="overflow-table">
    <div id="dvData"></div>
</div>
<!-- to dvData I render at code behind table--> 

<div class="overflow-table">
    <div id="dvData">
         <table class="overflow-table"> <!-- I try too something like this-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!!

[solution](https://codepen.io/szkut/pen/PXboNa?editors=1100)

Comment: I added link with example

Comment: This is approximately what I was going for with my answer below, is this what you mean? https://codepen.io/nickfindley/pen/QzGWPb

Comment: not exactly, I wanna scrollbars instead of red border

Comment: How about this (updated): https://codepen.io/nickfindley/pen/QzGWPb -- set a max-width and max-height on the div using vw and vh units so you don't have to hard code a size.

Comment: this is an answer! plz update your `Post Answer` and I will select it

Comment: Done! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a `max-width` and `max-height` on the `div` around the table. Use `vw` and `vh` units or percentages to avoid hard-coding width and height.

```
.window-overflow {
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 95vh;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

https://codepen.io/nickfindley/pen/QzGWPb